# Issue with Gstreamer under Qt in c++ : flow error

Tags: c++, opencv, gstreamer

I'm a beginner in Gstreamer, I need to get the frame from an UDP camera and convert it to an `cv::Mat`(OpenCV).
I run my camera stream like this :

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! \
   h264parse ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX port=5000
```

And in another terminal I can get the stream like this (and it works):

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5000 caps='application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264' ! \
rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink
```

So in my C++ code here is my C++ code :

`GstFlowReturn
new_preroll(GstAppSink *appsink, gpointer data) {
  g_print ("Got preroll!\n");
  return GST_FLOW_OK;
}

GstFlowReturn
new_sample(GstAppSink *appsink, gpointer data) {
  static int framecount = 0;
  framecount++;

  GstSample *sample = gst_app_sink_pull_sample(appsink);
  GstCaps *caps = gst_sample_get_caps(sample);
  GstBuffer *buffer = gst_sample_get_buffer(sample);
  const GstStructure *info = gst_sample_get_info(sample);

  // ---- Read frame and convert to opencv format ---------------

  GstMapInfo map;
  gst_buffer_map (buffer, &map, GST_MAP_READ);

  // convert gstreamer data to OpenCV Mat, you could actually
  // resolve height / width from caps...
  Mat frame(Size(320, 240), CV_8UC3, (char*)map.data, Mat::AUTO_STEP);
  int frameSize = map.size;

  // TODO: synchronize this....
  frameQueue.push_back(frame);

  gst_buffer_unmap(buffer, &map);

  // ------------------------------------------------------------

  // print dot every 30 frames
  if (framecount%30 == 0) {
    g_print (".");
  }

  // show caps on first frame
  if (framecount == 1) {
    g_print ("%s\n", gst_caps_to_string(caps));
  }

  gst_sample_unref (sample);
  return GST_FLOW_OK;
}

static gboolean
my_bus_callback (GstBus *bus, GstMessage *message, gpointer data) {
  g_print ("Got %s message\n", GST_MESSAGE_TYPE_NAME (message));
  switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (message)) {
    case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR: {
      GError *err;
      gchar *debug;

      gst_message_parse_error (message, &err, &debug);
      g_print ("Error: %s\n", err->message);
      g_error_free (err);
      g_free (debug);
      break;
    }
    case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
      /* end-of-stream */
      break;
    default:
      /* unhandled message */
      break;
  }
  /* we want to be notified again the next time there is a message
   * on the bus, so returning TRUE (FALSE means we want to stop watching
   * for messages on the bus and our callback should not be called again)
   */
  return TRUE;
}

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GError *error = NULL;

  gst_init (&argc, &argv);
     gchar *descr = g_strdup(
    "udpsrc port=5000 ! "
    "caps=application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)9000, encoding-name=(string)H264 ! "
    "rtph264depay ! "
    "avdec_h264 ! "
    "videoconvert ! "
    "appsink name=sink "

  );


  GstElement *pipeline = gst_parse_launch (descr, &error);

  if (pipeline== NULL) {
    g_print ("could not construct pipeline: %s\n", error->message);
    g_error_free (error);
    exit (-1);
  }

  /* get sink */
  GstElement *sink = gst_bin_get_by_name (GST_BIN (pipeline), "sink");

  gst_app_sink_set_emit_signals((GstAppSink*)sink, true);
  gst_app_sink_set_drop((GstAppSink*)sink, true);
  gst_app_sink_set_max_buffers((GstAppSink*)sink, 1);
  GstAppSinkCallbacks callbacks = { NULL, new_preroll, new_sample };
  gst_app_sink_set_callbacks (GST_APP_SINK(sink), &callbacks, NULL, NULL);

  GstBus *bus;
  guint bus_watch_id;
  bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus (GST_PIPELINE (pipeline));
  bus_watch_id = gst_bus_add_watch (bus, my_bus_callback, NULL);
  gst_object_unref (bus);

  GstStateChangeReturn test=gst_element_set_state (GST_ELEMENT (pipeline), GST_STATE_PLAYING);
  qDebug() <<test<< " this is the test";
  namedWindow("edges",1);
  while(1) {
    g_main_iteration(false);

      // TODO: synchronize...
    if (frameQueue.size() >10) {
      // this lags pretty badly even when grabbing frames from webcam
      Mat frame = frameQueue.front();
      imshow("edges", frame);
      cv::waitKey(30);
      frameQueue.clear();
    }
  }

  gst_element_set_state (GST_ELEMENT (pipeline), GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref (GST_OBJECT (pipeline));

  return 0;
}`

And I get the ERROR :

> Error: Internal data flow error.

I think it is from my declaration of my pipeline, but I can't find what's wrong with it.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I asked to remove Qt tag because there is no relation to it. IF the code is correct and why that could happen: I would try to make sure all the environment is correct on the machine that has the code failing.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `!` after `udpsrc port=5000`. That one is not present in your original pipeline. I haven't checked any further, maybe print out the pipeline and double check if its the desired one.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! That was the problem ! Stupid mistake .

Comment: Now I have a problem with videoconvert under gstreamer pipeline ... I must convert the image into RGB format so I do : gchar *descr = g_strdup(
    "udpsrc port=5000 "
    "caps=\"application/x-rtp\" ! "
    "rtph264depay ! "
    "avdec_h264 ! "
     "decodebin ! "
    "videoconvert ! "
    "video/x-raw,format=(string)RGB ! "
    "videoconvert ! "
    "appsink name=sink "   But the image is deformed . in C as well and in the terminal with the same command . Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Not sure why you have two videoconvert elements in there. Also the purpose of decodebin here seems to do nothing. But the real issues seems to be a misunderstanding how the data is stored in RGB and how you interprete it. But thats only an assumption since all I have is "it does not work".

Comment: Yeah thanks  for the comment  my issue was : http://imgur.com/a/bni6M       as you can see the image was deformed with a lot of art effects. We fixed it in resizing the frame from the camera udp , with smaller image we dont have this problem. We think that come from the wifi but without rgb conversion we don't have this problem . If i'm not clear enough please tell me . Sorry I'm a little lost in the see of Gstreamer and i have a lot of difficulties explaning my problem. thanks for your time. I will check those parameters futher .

Comment: Yes, this looks like you either have packet loss, resulting in broken decoder images, or transmission takes "too long" for the receiver and it skips the rest of the frames. Limiting UDP bandwidth or increasing the latency on the receiver may help here.